# Camel - Integrating with Existing Application

Tags: java, apache-camel

I currently work on a trading application that does not use camel.
It essentially takes in trades, does some processing and sends the details to an external system.

We now have a need to integrate with 3 new systems uusing FTP for 2 systems and JMS for 1 system.

I would like to use Camel in my application for these integrations. I have read a good chunk of camel in action but I was unclear on how we could kick off our camel routes

Essentially, we dont want to modify too drastically any part of the existing application  as its working well in production.

In the existing application, we generate a Trade Value Object and its from this object that that I want to kick off our camel integration.
I dont have a database table or jms queue where I can kick off the route from.

I had a quick look at the Chapter on Bean routing and remoting in the Camel in Action book but I wanted to get peoples advise first before proceeding with any steps.
What would be the best approach for this integration?

Thanks
Damien

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Camel's [POJO Producing](http://camel.apache.org/pojo-producing.html) feature that allows you to send a message to a camel endpoint from the java bean. If you have no need in JMS or DB you can use ["direct:"](http://camel.apache.org/direct.html) or ["seda:"](http://camel.apache.org/seda.html) or ["vm:"](http://camel.apache.org/vm.html) endpoint as `<from>` part of your route.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you need to do any extra configuration to pickup the bean that has the @Produce annotation? I tried a test there but I cant get the message from the bean to the route

Comment: @Damo there is an example project in Camel distribution (described here http://camel.apache.org/pojo-messaging-example.html) - you can see a configuration example here

Answer (score 3):

Pojo producing as Konstantin V. Salikhov stated. However, you need to be sure you have a spring application and are scanning your beans with spring or wire them.

"If a bean is defined in Spring XML or scanned using the Spring component scanning mechanism and a  is used or a CamelBeanPostProcessor then we process a number of Camel annotations to do various things such as injecting resources or producing, consuming or routing messages."

If this approach will add too much changes in your application, you could use a [ProducerTemplate](http://camel.apache.org/producertemplate.html) and just invoke a direct endpoint. (Or SEDA for that matter).

The choice of protocol here might be important. The direct protocol is a safe choice, since the overhead is simply a method call. Also, exceptions will propagate well through direct endpoints, as will transactions. As SEDA endpoints is asynchronous (like JMS) but does not feature persistence, there is a slight chance of loosing in flight data in case of a crash. This might or might not be an issue. However, with high load, the SEDA protocol stages better and give your application better resistance for load peaks.

Comment: Thanks for your response Petter.. it makes alot of sense